# hide form with css3 and show default div.

Tags: html, css

I only can use html5 and css3.
I have a form and I need simulate "send form data". After click in submit button I need to hide the form and show some default div (#result).
How can I do this (only css3 and html5, no javascript).

Thanks.

This is my HTML + CSS code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS CHALLENGE</title>
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400 "Raleway");
        @import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
        .global {
            background-color: #353535;
            font: 14px/21px "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
        }

        .backgound {
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            height: 530px;
            width: 400px;
            margin:0 auto 0 auto;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
        }

        #loginForm {
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            font-family: Raleway;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: small-caps;
            font-weight: 200;
            line-height: 26.4px;
        }

  .header {
   margin-left: 40px;
        }

  #triangle {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-left: 12px solid transparent;
   border-right: 12px solid transparent;
   border-top: 12px solid cornflowerblue;
   margin-top: 29px;
   left: 54px;
   position: relative;
  }

  #loginForm h2 {
            background: cornflowerblue;
            color: white;
            height: 55px;
            font-size: 2.5em;
            padding-top: 10%;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            font-family: Raleway;
            font-size: 39px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: small-caps;
            font-weight: 200;
            line-height: 26.4px;
        }

        .item {
            display: -webkit-box;
            height: 30px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto 15px;
            background-color: white;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        }

        #idMessage  {
            height: 160px;
        }

        #loginForm button{
            opacity: 0.5;
            transition:opacity .3s;
            -webkit-transition:opacity .3s;
            background-color: darkolivegreen;
            width: 308px;
            height: 60px;
            -moz-border-radius: 7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        #loginForm:valid button {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #result {
            display: none;
        }

        #result:target {
            display:block;
        }

        .myLoad {
            position: relative;
        }

        .myLoad i {
            position: absolute;
            top: 8px;
            left: 325px;
        }

#val {
    display: none;
}
.#idEmail:invalid #val {
        display: block;
}

input:invalid .val {
    display: block;
}

#idEmail:invalid, #idMessage:invalid{
    color: red;
}

#idEmail:valid, #idMessage:valid{
    color: green;
}


/* fa-spin*/
    </style>
</head>
<body class="global">
<div class="backgound">
    <form id="loginForm" action="#result" method="get">
        <h2>
   <span class="header">Contact Us!</span>
   <div id="triangle"></div>
  </h2>
        <div class="myLoad">
            <input class="item" id="idEmail" type="email"
                placeholder="Email" required>
            <i id="inval" class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
            <i id="val" class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
        </input>
        </div>
            <div class="myLoad">
            <input class="item" id="idSubject" type="text"
                placeholder="Subject">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="myLoad">
            <textarea class="item" id="idMessage" placeholder="Message"
                rows="10" cols="40" required></textarea>
            <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
        </div>
        <button class="item" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result" class="sended">Form sended</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You can do it with CSS if you have a class that tells you whether the form has been sent or not (e.g. a `sent` class that is added after clicking the button). However, the class must be added after clicking the button, and you can add classes to DOM nodes only if you can use JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track using the `:target` pseudo-class. However, you need to switch the order of the result div and the form, and then combine it with a general sibling selector, [see my example here](https://jsfiddle.net/wm4ox94n/).

(Using the button to submit the form doesnt quite seem to work, but I think that's because the iframing, hopefully it should work for you. Try clicking the test link on jsfiddle to navigate to #result.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit hmmm...

Is PHP an option?

If yes, you can direct the form to another page defined in the "action" attribute of the `<form>` tag, and there read out the input values via PHP and do something with them, i.e. display them or send them somewhere in an email.